# Firebase Android Debug Token Not Working (Flutter Project)

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I'm using the Firebase Phone-Auth and I've followed the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider) of the debug provider for Flutter Project but my phone authentication still shows the reCAPTCHA on the browser after requesting an OTP Code.

I've added the App Check debug token from my project to the Firebase console, added the SHA-256 fingerprint, and yet it still shows the reCAPTCHA window.

Comment: facing the same issue